# Is it possible to find the text by position using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file that contains some row ( 3 ) in a specific area of the page; is possibile to find all text in that specific area, and reaplace with a fixed string ?

Comment: You can remove former text in that area using itext redaction tools (pdfCleanup) and then draw your replacement text in the area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the text on some specified area one can create his own `IEventListener` and parse the page with it.

There is an iText7 official example that shows how to handle images in this way. It can be easily modified for your purposes by listening to `EventType.RENDER_TEXT` rather than `EventType.RENDER_IMAGE`. 
https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_31_MyImageRenderListener.java
https://github.com/itext/i7js-book/blob/develop/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part4/chapter15/Listing_15_30_ExtractImages.java

As @mkl suggested in the comments, replacing can be done by redacting the area and drawing the text upon it.
Please note that it's not sufficient just to draw a white div or summat upon the text you want to redact since it'll still be present in the page's content stream. Instead one can use iText's [pdfSweep](https://github.com/itext/i7j-pdfsweep). The redaction code will look summat:

```
    List <PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
    cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(pageNum, new Rectangle(215, 780, 10, 30), colorToDrawUponTheArea));
PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(pdfDocument, cleanUpLocations);
    cleaner.cleanUp();
```

Then one can use `ElementPropertyContainer#setFixedPosition` or `Canvas` to place the string on the redacted area.